resultado NaN en calculo de promedio javascript
estoy en enredado en un simple ejercicio que no puedo resolver
tomo los datos de una ventana emergente para luego calcular el promedio que muestra en una tabla del html, al terminar de ingresar los datos no me muestra el resultado del calculo si no que da una respuesta "NaN".
<thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Ramo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nota 1</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nota 2</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nota 3</th>
                        <th scope="col">Promedio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">HTML</th>
                        <td id="notaH1">Nota 1</td>
                        <td id="notaH2">Nota 2</td>
                        <td id="notaH3">Nota 3</td>
                        <td id="promH">Promedio</td>
                    </tr>
</tbody>


<script>
    var notaH1 = document.getElementById("notaH1");
    var notaH2 = document.getElementById("notaH2");
    var notaH3 = document.getElementById("notaH3");
    var promH = (parseFloat(notaH1) + parseFloat(notaH2) + parseFloat(notaH3))/3;
    document.getElementById("promH").innerHTML = promH;
    
    
    notaH1.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 1");
    notaH2.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 2");
    notaH3.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 3");
</script>


Fíjate que contiene las variables que intentas usar como su fueran numero.

Cambiar parseFloat(notaH1)  por parseFloat(notaH1.innerHTML)  y lo mismo para los otros 2.

contiene el numero que es ingresado por la ventana emergente, los registra en la tabla el problema es cuando se hace el calculo . la variable prom no se llena con el dato

@Yussef lo agregue pero sigue saliendo el mismo resultado. gracias

1.- notaH1 es un elemento HTML un TD, por eso parseFloat no produce resultado debes hacer parseFloat(notaH1.innerHTML)
2.- Calculas el promedio antes de pedir los números con prompt. El orden de las instrucciones de arriba hacia abajo. Por tanto, estas realizando cálculos con valores que no existen. Debes reorganizar las instrucciones


var notaH1 = document.getElementById("notaH1");
var notaH2 = document.getElementById("notaH2");
var notaH3 = document.getElementById("notaH3");

notaH1.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 1");
notaH2.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 2");
notaH3.innerHTML = prompt("Ingrese una nota HTML 3");

var promH = (parseFloat(notaH1.innerHTML) + parseFloat(notaH2.innerHTML) + parseFloat(notaH3.innerHTML)) / 3;
document.getElementById("promH").innerHTML = promH;
<table>
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Ramo</th>
      <th scope="col">Nota 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Nota 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Nota 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Promedio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">HTML</th>
      <td id="notaH1">Nota 1</td>
      <td id="notaH2">Nota 2</td>
      <td id="notaH3">Nota 3</td>
      <td id="promH">Promedio</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




muchas gracias, eso soluciono el problema
